# Android ProgressDialog Not Working

Tags: java, android, progressdialog, android-context

This code isn't working. The loading screen doesn't show, however if I take out the http.load() it works fine.

```
Context ctx = v.getContext();
dialog = ProgressDialog.show(ctx, "Login", "Logging in...");
http.load();
```

http code:

```
try
        {
            HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = newHttpPost("http://www.example.com/");

            HttpResponse rp = hc.execute(post);

            if(rp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK)
            {
                result = EntityUtils.toString(rp.getEntity());
            }
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

}

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "isn't working"?

Comment: Do you get an exception, other than IOException in http.load()? Is the http.load() blocking the execution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're calling `http.load()` from UI thread and it gets blocked until this call completes. You should use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) for that.